# JQuery Script - Appears correct but not working

Tags: jquery

We have script that is used for ensuring that required fields on an order form are filled out.  The script has worked but now no longer.  Not sure if it is the script or some other element in the page.  Would love some input - Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery('a.continueButton:first').unbind('click');    
jQuery("a.continueButton:first").click(function(event){    
var hollaback = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace(/javascript:/g, ''); 
event.preventDefault();  

if (jQuery("#Order0_PreviouslyAttended").val() == ''){    
alert("Please fill in your previous course details first"); 
jQuery("#Order0_PreviouslyAttended").focus();
return false;    

} else {    
if (jQuery("#Order0_DietaryNeeds").val() == ''){    
alert("Please let us know if you have any special dietary requirements"); 
jQuery("#Order0_DietaryNeeds").focus();
return false;

} else {    
if (jQuery("#Order0_Names").val() == ''){      
alert("Please select your preferred length of stay"); 
jQuery("#Order0_Names").focus();
return false;  

} else {    
if(jQuery('#agreement_checkbox').is(':checked')){
eval(hollaback);  
return true; 

} else {
alert("Please check the acknowledgement before proceeding");
jQuery("#agreement_checkbox").focus();
            }  
            }   
        }


});
jQuery(".paymentLabel:contains('Credit Card Type')").html('<b>Select Credit Card Type</b>');        //replace the text for Credit Card Type
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your code. You were missing some curlies.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery('a.continueButton:first').unbind('click');    
jQuery("a.continueButton:first").click(function(event){    
    var hollaback = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace(/javascript:/g, ''); 
    event.preventDefault();  

    if (jQuery("#Order0_PreviouslyAttended").val() == '')
    {    
        alert("Please fill in your previous course details first"); 
        jQuery("#Order0_PreviouslyAttended").focus();
        return false;    

    } 
    else 
    {    
        if (jQuery("#Order0_DietaryNeeds").val() == '')
        {    
            alert("Please let us know if you have any special dietary requirements"); 
            jQuery("#Order0_DietaryNeeds").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {    
            if (jQuery("#Order0_Names").val() == '')
            {      
                alert("Please select your preferred length of stay"); 
                jQuery("#Order0_Names").focus();
                return false;  
            } 
            else 
            {    
                if(jQuery('#agreement_checkbox').is(':checked'))
                {
                    eval(hollaback);  
                    return true; 
                } 
                else 
                {
                    alert("Please check the acknowledgement before proceeding");
                    jQuery("#agreement_checkbox").focus();
                }  
            }   
         }
    }


    });
    jQuery(".paymentLabel:contains('Credit Card Type')").html('<b>Select Credit Card Type</b>');        //replace the text for Credit Card Type
});
```

I have some qualms about how this is structured and you know that the "replace the text for credit card type" is outside of the event when this is correctly formated. You should reconsider what you are trying to accomplish and how you are going about it perhaps.